# Why my code is giving me data in 1 column it should give me in two different column

Tags: pandas, series

i need to know what is happening in my code? it should give data in separate columns it is giving me same data in a oath columns.

i tried to change the value of row variable but it didn't found the reason

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

import time
arrayofRequest= []
prices=[]
location=[]
columns=['Price', 'Location']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)


for i in range(0,50):
    arrayofRequest.append("https://www.zameen.com/Homes/Karachi-2-"+str(i+1)+".html?gclid=Cj0KCQjw3JXtBRC8ARIsAEBHg4mj4jX1zZUt3WzGScjH6nfwzrEqkuILarcmg372imSneelSXPj0fGIaArNeEALw_wcB")
    request = requests.get(arrayofRequest[i])

    soupobj= BeautifulSoup(request.content,"lxml")
#     print(soupobj.prettify())

    links =soupobj.find_all('span',{'class':'f343d9ce'})
    addresses =soupobj.find_all('div',{'class':'_162e6469'})
    price = ""
    for i in range(0,len(links)):
        price = str(links[i]).split(">")
        price = price[len(price)-2].split("<")[0]
        prices.append(price)

        address = str(addresses[i]).split(">")
        address = address[len(address)-2].split("<")[0]
        location.append(address)

        row=location[i]+","+prices[i]
        df = df.append(pd.Series(row, index=columns), ignore_index=False)
#         filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',filewriter.writerow(['Price', 'Location']),filewriter.writerow([prices[0],location[0]])
df.to_csv('DATA.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because of this:

`pd.Series(row, index=columns)`

try smthg like

`pd.DataFrame([[locations[i], prices[i]]], index=columns))`

However this could be done only once outside of your for loop

`pd.DataFrame(list(zip(locations, prices)), index=columns))`